# Fourier expansion of sine of cosine function

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

What is the Fourier expansion of $$\sin\left(A\cos(\omega t)\right),\qquad 0<A<1,$$ in the frequency $\omega$ domain?

Comment: Funny. W|A failed to find solution in standard time, Mathematica also thinks seemingly without end...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with the generating function for [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function):

$$e^{\frac{z}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(z) t^n$$

Substitute $t = ie^{i\theta}$ and using the fact for integer $n$, $J_{-n}(z) = (-1)^n J_{n}(z)$, one get:

$$e^{iz\cos\theta} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} J_n(z) i^n e^{in\theta}
= J_0(z) + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} i^n J_n(z) \cos(n\theta)$$

Expand this and compare the imaginary part of both sides, one can derive:

$$\sin(A\cos(\omega t)) = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n J_{2n+1}(A)\cos((2n+1)\omega t)$$

Comment: I found this in a book, could you comment on how it relates to the your method? [link to image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UU2dx.png)